# Why does $\sigma \vDash b$ if $\sigma \vDash a \rightarrow b$?

Tags: logic

I do not quite understand why this holds. If we have a model which satisfies $a \rightarrow b$ why does this model then also satisfy $b$ alone?

Since $\sigma \vDash a \rightarrow b$ is equivalent to $\sigma \vDash (\neg a \lor b)$ i can find an assignment for $\neg a$ that it becomes $true$ and because we have an or we can say $b=false$. In this case $\sigma$ would satisfy $(\neg a \lor b)$ and therefore $a \rightarrow b$ but not $b$ alone.

This implication is from the proof of the rule of consequences in Hoare logic using operational semantics.

Comment: Could you give a specific reference? I suspect that there might have been some misunderstanding.

Comment: @Memming Of course. It is actually from a university class of mine concerning this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic#Consequence_rule). We assume that $\sigma \vDash P_1 \rightarrow P_2$ and therefore $\sigma \vDash P_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is a typo here. As you observe, the statement as written is false. I suspect that the following was intended instead: $$\sigma, a\models b \quad\implies\quad \sigma\models a\rightarrow b.$$ This is true, and is called the **deduction theorem**.

*(Actually, strictly speaking the deduction theorem is for $\vdash$ instead of $\models$. But they are connected by the completeness theorem, and I've seen the term used for both facts.)*

Comment: Addendum to your last note: If one wants to avoid the term "deduction theorem" for $\vDash$, one may also call it the "**import-export theorem**".